# Where to get a web graph with corresponding web pages dataset

Tags: database, web-crawler, search-engine, pagerank, inverted-index

I'm trying to implement `PageRank` algorithm on a set of web pages, for that I need a sample `dataset` of web pages, and the web graph corresponding to them, this web graph represents the links between the pages that the data set contains.

I need the web graph so I can get the transition matrix and do the calculation needed. Example:

```
URL1 -> URL2
URL3390 -> URL5
```

`URLxxxx` is an id, somehow mapped to the corresponding web page

My question is: how/where can I get this resource (I've tried many links on the internet but nothing really helps), I would also like it to be not of a very large size, (internet connection limitation), if I can't have this as it is, could sou give me some advice on what I should do?

**Update:** for people who may consider this off topic, and they may be right, networks like Software Recommendation or on Computer Science, don't even have corresponding tags, and doesn't really fit the kind of this question, I appreciate your help.

Comment: [Same question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3709/60) on Software Rec.

Comment: @unor : Yes, I posted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be Site Visualizer is the tool you're looking for. The app has the feature to [generate visual sitemap](http://site-visualizer.com/visual-sitemap).

Download and install the app (Standard or Pro version), click *Create new project* toolbutton, type the URL of the website you need to crawl, and then click *Start* button.

After the crawling is finished, click *Draw* button on the *Visual Sitemap* tab. Graph of the website will be drawn as a set of pages (rectangles) and links (lines with arrows). Click on a box to select the certain page and highlight its outbound links:
[image: generate visual sitemap]

Dataset of all links of the website you can get by using [All Links report](http://site-visualizer.com/reports/links) (on the *Reports* tab). '*From URL*' and '*To URL*' columns are what you need.

Besides of that, you can represent a dataset of pages or links of the crawled website by using your particular SQL query. For instance, go to the *Database* tab, type the following query and click *Execute* toolbutton:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE link_type='A'
```

The resultset will contain only *A-tag* links, excluding images, CSS files, JS, etc.

The program has full-featured 30-days trial period, so you can carry out your tasks for free.

Comment: Thx for the anwser @Oleg, Indeed it is very useful I've just tested it, but still I can't export the map to a file where I can have both the webpages and the links between them, the XML sitemap provides only URL as they are, I mean no relations between them. Is there a way I can accomplish that ?

Comment: Run the report you need (e.g., All Links report), select all rows in resultset (Ctrl+A), then copy it (Ctrl+C). After that you can paste the data into MS Excel sheet, or smth like this.

Comment: thx again, that absolutely works, I still have one last question, can I use it to crawl a locally stored webpages ??

Comment: No, you cannot. Only website's pages.

Answer (score 1):

you might try searching for datasets used in supplementary information for PageRank papers.  Here's an example:
this paper: http://langvillea.people.cofc.edu/ReorderingPageRank.pdf

uses this dataset:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs685/2002fa/data/gr0.California
which supposedly contains 9,664 nodes and 16,773 links.  The links are at the end of the file and appear to be in a connection format similar to what you're looking for.

from this page (which also has other datasets):
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs685/2002fa/

here's a few other pages that aggregate network datasets:

1. http://snap.stanford.edu/data/, see particularly
   http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Stanford.html
2. http://www.datawrangling.com/some-datasets-available-on-the-web
3. http://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/resources.php

good luck!

Comment: For the http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs685/2002fa/data/gr0.California
Where can I find the content, I mean the mentioned webpages in the file, to download them on my machine ?

Comment: easiet way is probably to write a commandline script to pass the URL to curl.  'curl -L <URL> > file.txt' will put the webpage content into a file for you.  '-L' will be need for most of those URLs to allow redirecting.